# *VSCode - Code not working properly when first opened on VSCode. To-do list project

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

I think I got all the basic functionalities working fine for this little todo list project, but when I open it on my browser (Chrome) using VSCode, some functionalities seem to not loading properly. For example, in my case, when first opened on the browser, the cursor when hovering on "Add Task" is supposed to be "pointer" as you can see in CSS under #addTask ID, yet it still seems to be 'auto'.

I notice that in order for all functionalities to work properly, I must click on other tabs after opening the project on the browser.

Has anybody found themselves in a similar situation before? Or is it just me?

Thanks, guys.

P.S I'm using a MacBook Pro Retina Late 2012 High Sierra.

Does this ever happen to anybody?

```js
var remove = function(){
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}

function addTask(){
    document.getElementById('deleteTask').textContent = 'Delete Task';

    var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
    for(var i = 0 ; i < lis.length; i ++){
        var li = lis[i];
        li.style.cursor  = 'pointer'; 
        li.removeEventListener('click', remove);
    }

    //Get the element from input field
    var li = document.createElement('li'); // create a <li> </li>
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value; // Get the input from User

    if(userInput.trim() != ''){
        var userText = document.createTextNode(userInput);
        li.appendChild(userText);
        var ul = document.getElementById('unorder_list');
        ul.appendChild(li);
    } else {
        alert('Field cannot be empty');
        
    }
    
    document.getElementById('userInput').value = '';
    
    var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
    for(var i = 0 ; i < lis.length ; i ++){
       lis[i].style.cursor  = 'auto';
    }

}

function deleteAll(){
    var ul = document.getElementById('unorder_list');
    ul.innerHTML = '';
}

function deleteTask(){
    document.getElementById('deleteTask').textContent = 'Click to delete';

    //Click this button first, all the <li> is now clickable and when you click on one, it disappears!
    var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
    
    for(var i = 0 ; i < lis.length; i ++){
        var li = lis[i];
        li.style.cursor  = 'pointer'; 
        li.addEventListener('click', remove);
    }

}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


#title{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 100px;
  font-size: 90px;
}

input{
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 100px;
  left: 30%;  
}

#addTask{
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 30%; 
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  border-radius: 10%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#deleteTask{
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left:30%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  border-radius: 10%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#deleteAll{
  position: relative;
  top: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul{
  position: relative;
  top: 120px;
  left: 25%; 
  width: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
} 

ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

li:nth-child(odd){
  background: rgb(219, 169, 169);
}

ul li:hover{
  transition: 1s;
  background: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="author" content="Andy">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="title">Your to-do list</div>
    <input type='text' id="userInput" placeholder="Hmm, what should I do next...?"/>
    <span id="deleteTask" onclick="deleteTask()">Delete Task</span>
    <span id="addTask" onclick="addTask()">Add Task</span>
    <ul id="unorder_list">
    </ul>
    <div id="deleteAll" onclick="deleteAll()">Delete All Task</div>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="todo.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: How exactly do you open your project so it can be viewed on Chrome?

Comment: @yuriy636 I pressed Alt (option) + B or just right clicked the HTML file and selected "Open in default browser".